# Game canvas is not fitting the whole page when resized in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cocos2d-js

I created a cocos2d-javascript game and am testing it on Chrome. The HTML of the webpage is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/GIF" href="res/favicon.ico"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=100%, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
    <meta name="full-screen" content="yes"/>
    <meta name="screen-orientation" content="landscape"/>
    <meta name="x5-fullscreen" content="true"/>
    <meta name="360-fullscreen" content="true"/>
    <style>
        body, canvas, div {
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="padding:0; margin: 0; background: #000; width:100%; height:100%; margin: 0px;">
<script src="res/loading.js"></script>
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
<script src="frameworks/cocos2d-html5/CCBoot.js"></script>
<script cocos src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I set it up so that the canvas will fit the whole page. This is how the game looks (it is by default 500x500):

[image]

If I resize the window, the canvas will generally resize correctly. But **sometimes** it will have some sort or margin:

[image]

What is wrong? I imagine the problem is the HTML itself, rather than cocos2d.

It only seems to occur with Chrome. Firefox seems fine.

I am using Mac OSX Yosemite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
*, html {
margin:0 !important;
padding:0 !important;  
}
```

And I would suggest removing the properties inside the `body` `style` attribute(just for cleanliness), and leaving just properties inside the `style` tag inside the `head`.

Comment: Hm, no luck, but something does seem to have improved. The left side is never padded now. The only problem would be the bottom and right sides.

Comment: I got it working by adding `width:100% !important;
   height:100% !important;`